# How can I frame break from this example?

Tags: php, javascript, hidden, frames, clickjacking

A random website has decided to load one of my urls via the following code...

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/" width="1" height="1" />
```

I tried adding a javascript framebreaker to check and break out but that doesn't work for this. How can I make sure my site breaks out of this and is shown full browser instead of hidden? They are eating up valuable bandwidth. Thanks

Here is the framebreaker code I have already tried from within head as usual...

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"badsite.com") == true){
echo '<script language="Javascript">
<!-- 
if (top.location != self.location) 
top.location.replace(self.location);
}
//--> 
</script>';
}
```

Comment: What about blacklisting the remote server IP on your web server?

Comment: It's not their server that's loading my site, its every visitor to THEIR site loading mine hidden in the background. I know I could just htaccess block the referrer but I'd like to have a general breaker to stop anyone else from doing this in the first place.

Comment: Framebreakers only work against frames. You'll want to prevent hotlinking to the requested page.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: Eek, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The HTML is being parsed as an image. This throws an error and doesn't execute any client side code you might feed to it.

Comment: This is what I assumed but was just wondering if anyone out there had a solution aside from blocking the referrer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, this is not a frame break, and PHP code is not involved.

The only thing you can do is in the configuration of your server, such as adding a rule to force request to have a proper HTTP Referer.

If you use Apache, [you can upload a `.htaccess`on the server for this](http://regis.decamps.info/blog/2010/03/hotlinking/) (link on a blog post I wrote long ago)

```
# Prevent Files image hotlinking and bandwidth stealing
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/wp-content/uploads/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.exemple.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|flv|png)$ / [F,L]
```

Edit: in your case, you can do

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://nasty-site.exemple.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/
```

That way, all traffic coming from http://nasty-site.exemple.com/ is redirected to localhost and nobody is bothered

Comment: Setting up hotlink protection does not work to make my site go full browser instead of remaining in their 1x1 pixel "image" without blocking the referrer.

Comment: @Tyler I read your question too fast. I though the link was on an image on your site (like it happened to me). I suppose I give a better answer now. You can have both rules, of course

Comment: The prerequisite is that you know which site is linking your home page, but that should be fairly easy with the server logs

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

Easy Step-by-Step:

1- crate a folder same as:images

2- in images folder creat a folder by  name of:image_folder and put your image file in "image_folder"

3-creat a .htaccess file by this content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php 
</IfModule>
```

4- creat index.php in images folder by this content:

```
    <?
$filename  = urldecode(end(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
$subname = current(explode('.',$filename));

$extention = end(explode('.',$filename));
switch ($extention) {
    case 'gif':
        $mime = 'image/gif';
        break;
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'jpe':
        $mime = 'image/jpeg';
        break;
    case 'png':
        $mime = 'image/png';
        break;
    case 'ico':
        $mime = 'image/x-icon';
        break;
    default:
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        echo('image not finded');
        exit;
        break;
}
if(is_file("image_folder/".$filename)){
    header("Content-type: ".$mime);
    readfile("image_folder/".$filename);
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo('image not finded');
}
```

An explanation: **Now you can check referer in index.php easly**

Comment: This would be a bunch of unnecessary code/work when my main site can already check the referrer in the parent php file. I am looking for a way to make my site change to full browser instead of hidden in their tiny 1x1 pixel "image" without blocking them in htaccess